# Drawing points/particles in stageros

Tags: ros, filter, rospy, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this twist publisher working perfectly for the robot. I can see the range readings. I could use an independent cv.NamedWindow to visualize particles used in my custom particle filter. But I am wondering **if it's possible to draw these particles as points directly stageros**? (Say in the erratic-wander.world for example). I'm using rospy.

I would like to have something like these red dots:
youtu.be/4S-sx5_cmLU?t=2m35s

(Insufficient karma to post as a link.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49508/drawing-points/particles-in-stageros/) by [num3ric](https://answers.ros.org/users/3698/num3ric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, stageros node is limited in functionalities compared with stage. At this moment stageros is just suscribed to cmd_vel topic and have no services. Because of this I guess there is no way to draw on the initial world. If you find a way, please tell me ;)

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2012-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2